# Determine data type sizes using pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    char *p = (char *)0;
    int *q = (int *)0;
    float *r = (float *)0;
    double *s = 0;

    a = (int) (p+1);
    b = (int) (q+1);
    c = (int) (r+1);
    d = (int) (s+1);

    printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d);

    return 0;
}
```

As I've run it, it gives the output

```
1 4 4 8
```

From the output I assume it gives the sizes of data types(char, int, float and double) as output. But I don't understand how. Can someone please explain this program. What does (char *)0 means? What does (int)(p+1) do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though it is "working", its behavior is undefined by C standard. You might want to read about pointer arithmetic anyway.

Comment: get C book. Impossible to copy&paste

Comment: *"But I don't understand how."* - because the behaviour is undefined, the meaningless operations resulted in a supposedly meaningful result on your computer and compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does `(char *)0` means?

It casts `0` to a pointer. It is not necessary though. You could have used

```
    char *p = 0;
```

or

```
    char *p = NULL;
```

> What does `(int)(p+1)` do?

`p+1` evaluates to a pointer value. The `(int)` part casts the pointer to an `int`. It works on some platforms because the numerical difference between `p` and `p+1` is `sizeof(*p)`.

However, please note that this is undefined behavior. Don't use it in production code. Use the standard supported mechanism to get the size of a type -- `sizeof(type)`.

```
int a = sizeof(char);
int b = sizeof(int);
int c = sizeof(float);
int d = sizeof(double);

printf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d);
```

You could preserve the type that `sizeof` evaluates to by using `size_t` for the variables.

```
size_t a = sizeof(char);
size_t b = sizeof(int);
size_t c = sizeof(float);
size_t d = sizeof(double);

printf("%zu %zu %zu %zu", a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: ... or even better `size_t` + `%zu`

Comment: But why is this undefined behavior? What type of wrong answer can it give?

Comment: The standard does not allow you to evaluate `NULL + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, pointers and integers are interchangeable. So:

`(char *)0` tells the compiler to look at the `int` 0 as if it were the address of a pointer to `char`. It then assigns that to `p`, a pointer to `char`.

C allows pointer arithmetic, so the expression `p+1` computes the address where the compiler would put another `char` after `p`. The difference between the addresses of `p` and `p+1` should be the size of **1** `char` in bytes.

To make sure C recognizes that as an `int` when it prints it out, the assignment `a = (int) (p+1);` casts `p+1` (an address) to an `int`. Effectively, that's the size of a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse each parts:

```
char *p = (char *)0;
```

A chart pointer is created and initialized to 0. The `(char *)` is here to cast the 0 to a char adress. So the pointer `p` points to the adress 0.

```
a = (int) (p+1);
```

`(p+1)` is the next adress after the current one (`0`) for a `char*` (p's current type). the `(int)` is there for the cast once again. For each type it will give the size because its value is the distance between the 1st adress and the second one.